# Is it possible to disable github image anonymized camo proxy

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I have a documentation repo on Gihtub and we've used cloudfront/s3 cdn in past for thoses images in blog posts. But we recently moved to github private repo for documentation. The problem is Github uses it's [anonymized proxy](https://help.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls/) to hash images and, all the images src is coming out as below instead the actual path :

```
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/wqerasfasdfasdfadsfasfasdf
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/xyxysyssadfasdfadsddfweras
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/asfdasdfasfassdfasdfasdfaa
.....
```

Is there any option on Github.com to disable this behavior? As our images are not private or no problem in having the same src as we upload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github image without camo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857193/github-image-without-camo)

Comment: Already has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857193/github-image-without-camo ), this is a duplicate.